# geodjango gdal 3 coordinates order changes

Tags: django, gdal, geodjango

Ive been setting an existing geodjango project in ubuntu 20.04, and the existing databases, fixture created, are all read backwards, (lat, long) (long,lat), I finally found the change and its the gdal verison, I was working with the 2.4 version, in ubuntu 20 I have the gdal version 3, and the change seems to be intended:

[GDAL 3.0 Coordinate transformation (backwards compatibility (?))](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1546)

as a workaround there is a SetAxisMappingStrategy(OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER) method

my question is, how do I setup my project for existing and new models being read correctly?, since the backwards reading exist in the admin, pages, serializers, etc

thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems this problem has been fixed in [Django 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#django-contrib-gis) by [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/58f1b07e49a98bb391c9e38b91f078ab2c302703) and [this other commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/91e287cce0561b647e7b7fb96dd415567512f279).